# brute force not working for this matrix

Tags: algorithm, matrix

In a 2X2 matrix, how can we find number of matrices such that there trace is N, determinant is positive and all entries are positive too. So if matrix is so d = N-a and for determinant to be positive,How can we calculate efficiently number of pairs (a,b) such that a*b<=n where n ranges from 1 to N-1?

Comment: Should matrix elements be integers?

Comment: Didn't you just [post this question under a different account](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22885778/efficient-way-other-than-brute-force-for-this-matrix)?

Comment: This question appears to be from a [running contest](http://www.codechef.com/APRIL14/problems/CNPIIM) at CodeChef. Quoting their [Code of Conduct](http://discuss.codechef.com/questions/18662/does-codechef-have-any-code-of-conduct/18667), "Do not ask or discuss any aspect of any CodeChefs’ problem during an ongoing contest on any other platform, online or offline. Discussion of strategy should be avoided during the contest and postponed till the end." So, it is basically bad sportsmanship to discuss that until the contest is over.

Comment: Sorry, did not had that information when answering. Should I delete my answer? But I don't think it helps much to really solve the problem stated at CodeChef.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming we have a matrix `m={{a,b},{c,d}}`, then we have:

- `trace(m) = N => a+d = N => d = N - a`
- `det(m) >= 0 => a*d - b*c >= 0 => a*(N-a) >= b*c`

Thus for an arbitrary but fixed `a < N` we can compute `d=N-a`, `q:=a*(N-a)` and only have the constraint `b*c <= q` left.

Now if elements can be real numbers you have infinite solutions by choosing a `b > 0` and computing `c = q/b`.

If elements should be integers, you have to find pairs `(b,c)` such that the `b*c <= q`. You find all solutions as follows:

- choose a `0 < b <= q`
- compute `cmax=floor(q/b)` (where floor is rounding down)
- all pairs `(b,1), ..., (b,cmax)` are possible solutions

In total:

```
for(int a=1; a<N; a++) {
     int q = a*(N-a);
     for(int b=1; b<=q; b++) {
         int cmax = floor(q/b);
         for(int c=1; c<=cmax; c++) {
             std::cout << "(a,b,c,d)=" << a << "," << b << "," << c << "," << N-a << std::endl;
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: can it be optimized further?